# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import. -> @import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/bootstrap.scss';

Tags: angular, npm, github-actions, node-modules, ngx-datatable

I am using `@swimlane/ngx-datatable` in one of my Angular Projects,
when I do `ng build --configuration=myconfig` on my local system, it builds without any errors and it even runs well by doing `ng serve`.

The problem is when I try to run same commands on Github Actions it fails with following errors:

```
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
13 │ @import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/bootstrap.scss';
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src/styles.scss 13:9  root stylesheet
    at processResult (/home/runners/actions-runner/_work/ui/ui/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:713:19)
    at /home/runners/actions-runner/_work/ui/ui/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:819:5
    at /home/runners/actions-runner/_work/ui/ui/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:400:11
    at /home/runners/actions-runner/_work/ui/ui/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:252:18
    at context.callback (/home/runners/actions-runner/_work/ui/ui/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.callback (/home/runners/actions-runner/_work/ui/ui/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:54:7)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (/home/runners/actions-runner/_work/ui/ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/sass/sass-service.js:134:25)
    at Worker.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:236:53)
    at MessagePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:736:20)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have imported all the scss files for datatable in my `styles.scss` file as:

```
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.css';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/bootstrap.scss';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.scss';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/dark.scss';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/assets/icons.css';
```

Following is my angular config:

```
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.0.0",
---
---
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.7",
"@angular/cli": "~12.2.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
---
---
node version: 16.17.1
```

And I can see the path of scss files in the **node_modules** in my local machine.
How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the bootstrap css included in your [angular.json](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration)? It should look something like this:

```
"projects": {
  "your-project": {
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
          ...
          "styles": [
            "./node_modules/path/to/css/bootstrap.css",
            "src/styles.scss"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Although that doesn't really explain why the build proces isn't failing locally. Are you sure you're running the exact same command?

Comment: Hello, I am not using bootstrap in my project, but a custom variant of it by adding its cdn in index.html file. But out of all @swimlane imports, if I go commenting them one by one, the next one gives import error. And yes, I am using exact same command while running or building app locally and on github actions :)

Comment: It's not possible to use scss imports by adding it to your index.html. Scss needs the imports when its compiling and adding it to your html means it is only available during runtime. Have you tried adding it to the styles array in your angular.json?

Comment: the custom bootstrap I am using via cdn is not scss but a css. The error I am getting is not of bootstrap but the bootstrap.scss for @swimlane/datatable. Basically on runtime, it is not finding those files in the imported paths. It is working fine locally, as I can see the files in the node_modules path, but not same using github actions